# Do Christadelphians celebrate Christmas?

Tags: christmas, christadelphians

I noticed from other questions that Christadelphians do not accept some doctrines shared by mainstream Christian religions, for example that of hellfire or that Jesus is part of a Trinity and is equal to God. They seem to share a view with some other faiths that Christianity was corrupted some time after the 1st century.

Based on this I wanted to ask about Christian celebrations that seem to have a pagan origin, such as Christmas. Do Christadelphians celebrate Christmas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is some do... some don't.

I personally don't because I've looked into where many of the traditional Church traditions and symbols came from. Christmas and its origins in Pagan worship, and I know of many other Christadelphians who don't like Christmas for the same reasons. We are not Pagan we are Christian... Pagan Rome persecuted the early Christians for their faith. Many were martyred because they refused to forsake Christ and revert to Paganism. So it doesn't seem right to me personally to then go and adopt elements of Pagan worship.

Others just see it as a commercially driven bank holiday, a break from work. They don't see anything wrong with putting pretty lights up or a tree to brighten the place up, and sharing presents like everyone else does. They either don't know the Pagan roots of Christmas, or don't care all that much.

From the Accepted Answer:

> The Christadelphians do not celebrate religious holidays nor do they practice Christmas because it is not mentioned in the Bible.

The quote above is technically correct, but I think it's taken slightly out of context in terms of providing an answer to the question asked. I think the writer is saying that we don't have feasts/holidays that we celebrate because we are Christadelphian, i.e. official Christadelphian holidays that we keep because we are Christadelphians. Technically I guess we do have one in a sense, taking holiday literally as "holy day"... then our holy day is a Sunday when we meet every week to do as Christ says "do this in remembrance of me".

In terms of the biblical feasts, which I think the author is referring to. We don't keep the feasts and holy days given under the law of Moses, because it says Christ fulfilled the law and all the sacrifices in his self sacrifice - "Christ offered once for all".

This doesn't mean individual Christadelphians don't get involved in national holidays/celebrations to some degree or another.

You will find that there often isn't a single answer to the question "what do Christadelphians believe"... we agree on the core principles and then there is some variation on topics such as this.

Answer (score 2):

**Do Christadelphians celebrate Christmas?**

The short answer is **no**.

> The Christadelphians do not celebrate religious holidays nor do they practice Christmas because it is not mentioned in the Bible. However they are active in the community through Sunday-School programs and summer camps and are encouraged to do so. They are taught to be tolerant of other religious groups, along with intermingling, but are forbid from participating other religious group’s activities. - [Chrsitadelphians](https://wrldrels.org/2016/10/09/chrsitadelphians/)